# Angular material - To load date in 3 different input elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a basic example with angular material datapicker:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

I would like to know, if is possible to use this plugin for to load a date in three different inputs elements.

```
<input name="day"  /> <input name="month" /> <input name="year" />
```

Comment: you want to bind them seaprately?

Comment: Exactly, when I select a date, the day will be put in an input, the month in another and the year in another.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the selected date value on **`ng-change`**, and split the day,month,year using javascript and bind them to the input box,

```js
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.bind = function() {
      $scope.date = $scope.myDate;
      $scope.month = $scope.date.getUTCMonth() +1 ;
      $scope.day = $scope.date.getUTCDate() +1;
      $scope.year = $scope.date.getUTCFullYear();
    }
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.css">

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <form >
      <md-content>
        <md-datepicker ng-change="bind()" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <label>label</label>
          <input required type="text" ng-model="month" />
        </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <label>label</label>
          <input required type="text" ng-model="day" />
        </md-input-container>
         <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <label>label</label>
          <input required type="text" ng-model="year" />
        </md-input-container>
      </md-content>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```